# Listing employees and their project tasks

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database (SQL Server 2008) looks like this:

> People 1 -- * TaskPersons * -- 1 Tasks * -- 1 Project

The `GROUP BY` part of the query is quite long, all because of the `COUNT` aggregate.  This seems to perform reasonably well.  I would like to know if there is a more concise way of writing this.

```
use Projects
SELECT COUNT(t.id), ppl.Name, ppl.Birthdate, ppl.Title, ppl.Role, ppl.Status, ppl.Warehouse, ppl.StartDate, ppl.SalaryBand, ppl.Salary,p.Title FROM People ppl
JOIN TaskPersons tp On tp.PersonId = ppl.Id
JOIN Tasks t ON t.Id = tp.TaskId
JOIN Projects p ON p.Id = t.ProjectId
GROUP BY ppl.Name, ppl.Name, ppl.Birthdate, ppl.Title, ppl.Role, ppl.Status, ppl.Warehouse, ppl.StartDate, ppl.SalaryBand, ppl.Salary, p.Title
```

Comment: If you group by project title, and there is a one-to-one correspondence between projects and tasks, then won't the count of tasks be 1 for every row?

Comment: Thank you, my relationship is listed in correctly, I have revised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `GROUP BY` in a sub-select.

```
SELECT  personTaskProject.TaskCount,
        ppl.Name,
        ppl.Birthdate,
        ppl.Title,
        ppl.Role,
        ppl.Status,
        ppl.Warehouse,
        ppl.StartDate,
        ppl.SalaryBand,
        ppl.Salary,
        personTaskProject.Title
    FROM
        People ppl,
        (SELECT COUNT(t.id) TaskCount, tp.PersonId, p.Title
            FROM TaskPersons tp
                JOIN Tasks t
                    ON t.Id = tp.TaskId
                JOIN Projects p
                    ON p.Id = t.ProjectId
            GROUP BY tp.PersonId, p.Title) AS personTaskProject
    WHERE ppl.Id = personTaskProject.PersonId;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ffc5/2)

Comment: I did not test this to see if there was any performance difference, but it definitely looks cleaner.